# xmlrpc.py permission denied whole running the supervisor

Tags: python, php, laravel, jobs, supervisord

I need to run the laravel jobs in the background and for that reason, I need to run the supervisor on the Linux server.
Whenever I try this

```
supervisorctl reread
```

It returns this error.

> error: <class 'PermissionError'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560

I tried to change the permission of this file

```
 chmod u+X /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py
```

It returns this error

> chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py': Operation not permitted

Any reason why it is not working? I recently upgraded the PHP to 8.1. Is this why it causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem as you, I used `sudo` at the beginning of the command and it worked fine

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
```